# Bootstrap tooltip on focus with different field names

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have some code written out to show the bootstrap tooltip on focus of an input.

```js
$('input[type=text][name=secondname]').tooltip({
    placement: "right",
    trigger: "focus"
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<input data-toggle="tooltip" title="tooltip on second input!" type="text" placeholder="Focus me!" name="secondname"/>
<input data-toggle="tooltip" title="tooltip on third input!" type="text" placeholder="Focus me!" name="thirdname"/>
```

I have multiple fields in my form and each one needs to show a tooltip.  Is there a way to get the name from each input field for the script above? The fields are dynamic and constantly added or removed.  So I don't want to have to keep updating the script with old / new fields.

Comment: Be careful using bootstrap and jquery together, I recommend you to download jquery without tooltip widget, sometimes it enters in conflict with bootstrap tooltip widget.

Comment: @VinicioAjuchan Did you make a typo in your comment? jQuery is a dependency for Bootstrap's javascript components.

Comment: @JoshJanusch you are right, it occurs with jQuery UI. don't keep in mind my previous comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need the tooltip in all of them you can just use:

```
$('input[type=text]').tooltip({
     placement: "right",
     trigger: "focus"
});
```

If you dont need it in all of your input texts, consider using a class.

```js
$('.tooltipped').tooltip({
     placement: "right",
     trigger: "focus"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<input class="tooltipped" data-toggle="tooltip" title="tooltip on second input!" type="text" placeholder="Focus me!" name="secondname"/>

<input class="tooltipped" data-toggle="tooltip" title="tooltip on third input!" type="text" placeholder="Focus me!" name="thirdname"/>
```

Comment: Oh really? that simple?  Just make one for each type of input? or can i do `$('input')`  ?

Comment: You can use  $('input') yes

Answer (score 1):

You can also init tooltips for all type=text "tooltipable" inputs, based on the presence of the title attribute (so you know you want to show tooltip for it):

```js
$(':text[title]').tooltip({
    placement: "right",
    trigger: "focus"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<input data-toggle="tooltip" title="tooltip on second input!" type="text" placeholder="Focus me!" name="secondname"/><br>
<input data-toggle="tooltip" title="tooltip on third input!" type="text" placeholder="Focus me!" name="thirdname"/>
```